# Find complexity of recursive log algorithm with floors and ceilings

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I have this ugly algorithm (yes, it's a computer science course, so it's ugly on purpose). We have to find its complexity using different methods. One of the methods is backwards substitutions. Just by looking at the algorithm, it seems obvious that its complexity will be somewhere in the (log (n - m)) range, since the instance size is divided by three on every recursive call.

```
Function WeirdSort(Array[m..n])
    if (m < n) then
        if (A[m] > A[n]) then
            temp = A[m]
            A[m] = A[n]
            A[n] = temp
        end if
        if (m + 1 < n) then
            index = floor((n - m + 1) / 3)
            WeirdSort(A[m..n - index])
            WeirdSort(A[m + index..n])
            WeirdSort(A[m..n - index])
        end if
    end if
end Function
```

But I'm trying to understand how I can reach this answer through the backwards substitutions method. More specifically, I'm stuck at trying to deal with the numerous floor() and ceiling() that start showing up for the size of the array, and how I am supposed to deal with them.

My instinct tells me that they can't be just brushed aside, but maybe it's what I'm supposed to do?

Also, considering the fact that the algorithm does not end earlier if the array is already sorted, I think the worst and best case are be the same, but that could be wrong too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you but the complexity is far away from `log(x)`.

Assume worst case where `m=1` what your doing is recursion for 2/3 of the elements 3 times.

`T(n) = 3*T(2n/3) + 1`

Using master theorm `==>` `T(n) = O(n^2.7~)`

Comment: Thank you for your input, when I went through the other techniques I ended realized that my estimate was very far off. On the other hand, you didn't really answer the question, which was about the process to reach that answer using the backwards substitutions method. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: @KaitoKid not really. I am not familiar with this method.